Are there any additional constraints on what can happen in a Python thread?
Say I have some function foo.
Consider snippet A:
args = # some args
foo(*args)

And consider snippet B:
import threading
args = # some args
thread = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=args)
thread.start()
thread.join()  # yes, I do mean to immediately join after starting

I want to know what sorts of things (if anything) I could do in foo such that A and B behave differently (eg crash or different run time). One example of something that I think might be different, is if foo tries to create threads or processes of its own? I'm not sure.
I'm also happy to exclude talking about overhead in creating the thread. I really mean just the running of the code in foo.
The thought experiment serves to hopefully answer my main question.

Some GUI libraries (and maybe other libraries) may have problems if their functions are called from multiple threads. Another problem occurs if thread-local storage is used.
